# Is there a way to pin a TabPage so it will be visible even when scrolling?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` in a `Form`. I'm adding tabs programatically to it. The `Multiline` property is false, so when they don't fit the area, the left and right arrows appear. But the first couple of tabs are special ones, they should not moved to the left when the right arrow is clicked, they should remain where they are. Is there a way to do this, like pinning a tab in a browser?
I was thinkig about catching the event of clicking the tabheader arrows, and positioning the first tabs to their original location, but I don't know which event can handle that, and the repositioning would really work.
Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in TabControl that will help you implement this.  If you don't want to create your own TC from scratch (don't) then consider nesting two tab controls.  So the outer one with 3 tabs and the inner on the 3rd tabpage.

Comment: That's bad news :( Anyway, thanks for suggesting a replacement!